# How to keep vlcj consistent when layout changes in JavaFx

Tags: java, swing, layout, javafx, vlcj

I have developed one desktop application using swing under which i have used JavaFx components, i have a few camera which i drag to the 2*2 layout view, it's working fine, now as soon as i changed the layout from 2*2 to 4*4, the view gets changed, then later on the dragged camera remain same on the canvas, but the streaming coming from the camera initially stops and then starts, i just want the video stream  coming from the camera to remain consistent, without restarting it, what i have did now, is to release the Media player , Created the updated Canvas and Add it into the panel, but i guess it's not a proper solution, can anyone help me out with this issue, thanks well in advance.
Any kind of help is highly appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not remove the media player `Canvas` from the frame component hierarchy, nor can you hide it.

You must do something else like minimise it's size to 0,0 use a custom layout manager and move it's position to 0,0 or -1,-1 may work.

To emulate hiding, you could use a `CardLayout` with a video view and a blank view and switch between them.

There's an example in the vlcj test sources that shows one approach: https://github.com/caprica/vlcj/blob/master/src/test/java/uk/co/caprica/vlcj/test/layout/AdaptiveLayoutTest.java